# Problem on running project with remote git repository using mlflow

Tags: conda, mlflow, mlops

I am using mlflow run with a GitHub uri.
when i run this command :

```
 mlflow run https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow-example.git
```

i got that error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\mlflow.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mlflow\cli.py", line 205, in run
    projects.run(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mlflow\projects\__init__.py", line 337, in run
    submitted_run_obj = _run(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mlflow\projects\__init__.py", line 105, in _run
    submitted_run = backend.run(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mlflow\projects\backend\local.py", line 83, in run
    work_dir = fetch_and_validate_project(project_uri, version, entry_point, params)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mlflow\projects\utils.py", line 138, in fetch_and_validate_project
    work_dir = _fetch_project(uri=uri, version=version)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mlflow\projects\utils.py", line 153, in _fetch_project
    use_temp_dst_dir = _is_zip_uri(parsed_uri) or not _is_local_uri(parsed_uri)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mlflow\projects\utils.py", line 110, in _is_local_uri
    resolved_uri = pathlib.Path(_parse_file_uri(uri)).resolve()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py", line 1215, in resolve
    s = self._flavour.resolve(self, strict=strict)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py", line 215, in resolve
    s = self._ext_to_normal(_getfinalpathname(s))
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'https:\\github.com\\mlflow\\mlflow-example.git'
```

But when it work with local project

I try to manipulate the conda environments but still the same problem .